# How to store whole a paragraph as one element of array in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, array

I am using the following code to read data from a file `abcd.txt`
and try to store in an array `parameters`, I am able to store `619617` in `parameter[0]` and `update` in `parameters[1]` but in `parameters[2]` I am not able to get the whole certificate. Please help me how to achieve this:

```
    filename="/home/abcd.txt"
    i=1
    index=0
        while read -r line
        do
            i=$line
            parameters[$index]=$(echo $i | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
            i=$((i+1))
            index=$((index+1))
            if [ "$index" == "3" ]
             then
                break
            fi
        done < "$filename"
        echo ${parameters[0]} ${parameters[1]} ${parameters[2]}
#       python /opt/symstream/bin/configure.py ${parameters[0]} ${parameters[1]} ${parameters[2]}
```

filename contains the following data:

```
cat abcd.txt

serial_no=619617
action=update
certificate=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with `while read` you are reading the file line by line. As the certificate spreads among multiple lines (with explicit newline characters), you cannot simply read it in as you do. If all files are like this and do not have multiple certificates or any other content, you can do this:

Delete lines 1 and 2, remove `certificate=` and read rest of file as array element (then remove newlines with `tr`).

```
arr[2]="$(sed '1,2d;s/certificate=//' abcd.txt | tr -d '\n' )"
```

I honestly also do not consider it helpful to loop over just three elements with differing complexity. Thus the first two elements would simply be:

```
arr[0]="$( awk -F'=' 'NR == 1 { print $2 }' abcd.txt )"
```

(same for second element with `NR == 2` ) or with `sed` as above

```
arr[0]="$(sed -n '1s/.*=//p' abcd.txt)"
```

(same for second element with `2s...`)

Comment: If the answer worked for you, consider accepting it - it will both reward Fiximan for his work, and help others find working solution for the problem, shall anyone encounter similar one.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapfile -t parameters < <(sed '1,4s/.*=//' abc)
parameters[2]=$(printf '%s\n' "${parameters[@]:2}")
```